# Knockout mapping nested objects binding not updating when they are null

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using ko.mapping.fromJSON I can bind from JSON as long as the nested objects are defined. When I update the nested objects to be null or empty then the binding breaks.

In this code I have five different datasets which I iterate through using the model.nextDataset function. When the dataset gets to the fourth and fifth variation it breaks the binding to the inner object.

```
var datasets = ["{\"id\": 1,\"reference\": \"reference1\",\"inner\": {\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"name1\"}}",
    "{\"id\": 1,\"reference\": \"reference2\",\"inner\": {\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"name2\"}}",
    "{\"id\": 1,\"reference\": \"reference3\",\"inner\": {\"id\": null,\"name\": null}}",
    "{\"id\": 1,\"reference\": \"reference3\",\"inner\": {}}",
    "{\"id\": 1,\"reference\": \"reference3\",\"inner\": null}"];

var mapping = {
    'create': function (options) {
        return new Model(options.data);
    },
        'key': function (data) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
    },
        'inner': {
        'create': function (options) {
            return new InnerModel(options.data);
        }
    },
        'key': function (data) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
    }
};
/*
var innerMapping = {
    'key': function(data) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
    }
};
*/
var InnerModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.innerName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.name() + " computed";
    }, self);
};

var Model = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
    self.innerName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.inner.name() + " computed";
    }, self);
}

var model = {
    dataset: ko.observable(0),
    model: ko.mapping.fromJSON(datasets[0], mapping, model),
    nextDataset: function () {
        model.dataset(model.dataset() + 1);
        if (datasets.length === model.dataset()) {
            model.dataset(0);
        }
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(datasets[model.dataset()], mapping, model.model);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Accompanying html:

```
<div id="testko">
    <p>Dataset: <span data-bind="text: dataset"></span><p>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: model.reference" /><br>
    <div data-bind="with: model.inner"><input type="text" data-bind="value: innerName" /><br></div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: model.innerName" /><br>
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: nextDataset" value="Next Dataset" />
</div>
```

I have made a jsfiddle to try and demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4KN/

I am sure that I am mapping incorrectly somehow but I haven't been using knockout long enough to be able to tell why.

Comment: You are accessing inner.name but inner is null!

Answer (score 0):

Your computed observable is falling over because it is accessing self.name() where self is set to null - this is normal behaviour for the mapping plugin and your correct usage of the with binding is stopping the issue that most people run in to in this scenario. The mapping plugin cannot create an object structure for a null object.

The problem is that you are getting a javascript error in the innername computed observable and therefore the knockout library does not continue to run - just add a null check around the self.name() as you are essentially doing with the "with" binding.